# How do I trigger a BulletedList in LinkButton-mode with javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, bulletedlist

I have a BulletedList in asp.net that is set to DisplayMode="LinkButton". I would like to trigger the first "bullet" from a javascript, can this be done? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have the BulletedList as

```
<asp:BulletedList runat="server" ID="MyLovelyBulletedList" DisplayMode="LinkButton">
    <asp:ListItem Text="My Lovely Text 1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="My Lovely Text 2" />
</asp:BulletedList>
```

... then you can fire the "onclick" event like this (cross-browser):

```
var links = document.getElementById('<%= MyLovelyBulletedList.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('a');

var targetLink = links[0];

if (targetLink.fireEvent)
{
    // IE
    targetLink.fireEvent("onclick");
}
else if (targetLink.dispatchEvent)
{
    // W3C
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

    targetLink.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: The targetLink.fireEvent("onclick"); line doesn't seem to work. Using alert I can see that  targetLink is the correct link, but it won't fire.

Comment: rather strange - i'll try to run it again.

as a side-note, if you wish to simply make a post-back, you could call 

__doPostBack ('<%= MyLovelyBulletedList.ClientID %>', 0);

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me. For some reason it just "fires" the first hyperlink on the page instead.

Comment: This solution works in Opera and Google Chrome, but not in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what Alexander indicated except that you could use jQuery to fire the event and depend on their cross-browser support rather than maintain it on your own.

```
$('#<%= MyLovelyBulletedList.ClientID %>')
    .contents()
    .find('a:first')
    .trigger('click');
```

Comment: that too :) it looks so damn good with jQuery! I guess that soon we'll make John Resig chapels all over the world...

Comment: and... it could be written as
$('#<%= MyLovelyBulletedList.ClientID %> > a:first').trigger('click');

Comment: We don't use jQuery as of now, but damn that looks smooth :)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing it seems the only dependent way to do this is by manually firing the __doPostBack-script like so:

```
__doPostBack('MyLovelyBulletedList', '0');
```

as suggested by [Alexander Gyoshev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25427/alexander-gyoshev)